# issue MIME type after adding ajax code in wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've got an issue with a weird behavior.

i wrote a custom javascript code that make an ajax call on a php controller located at the root folder of my wordpress installation.
But when i go to my wordpress page : https://www.altaisweb.fr/audit-de-positionnement-google-2/
All the css / js include failed because of a MIME type issue.

The weird thing is that when i go to this page by an inside link : menu, ect for the first time, all is working well but when i go on it with an external link like above the issue append

there is the js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery('#search').on('click', function(){

    var url =  jQuery('#url').val();
    var keyword =  jQuery('#key').val();

    keyword = keyword.replace(/ /g, '-_-');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.altaisweb.fr/getPosition.php",
        data: {search: keyword, url:url},
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            jQuery('.message span').empty();
            jQuery('.message span').append( result);

            var tt = ' ème';

            if(parseInt(jQuery('#incre').html()) == 1)
                tt=' er';

            if(jQuery('#incre').length){
                jQuery('#pos').empty();
                jQuery('#pos').append(''+jQuery('#incre').html()+''+tt);
                jQuery('#pos').show();
            }
            else{
                jQuery('#pos').empty();
                jQuery('#pos').append('> 10 ème');
                jQuery('#pos').show();
            }
            jQuery('#buttoncc').show();

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
        },

    });
});
```

there is my php code :

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");


$search = $_GET['search'];
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ip = $_GET['ip'];

//echo $search;
//die;

$search = str_replace('-_-', '+',$search);
$res = '';

$tt=' er';


$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&output=search&q='.$search);

$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('div[class=g]') as $element) {
           $i++;
    foreach($element->find('cite') as $h3) 
    {
        if(strpos($h3->plaintext, $url) !== false){
            if($i != 1)
                $tt=' ème';
            if($i >= 5)
                $res = '<strong>Bravo !</strong> Vous êtes actuellement <span id="incre">'.$i.'</span>'.$tt.' dans les résultats de recherche Google. <br> Vous faites partie des sites internet qui sont <strong>visibles par 90% des internautes !</strong> <br> Vos autres termes clés sont-ils positionnés sur la première page Google ?';
            else
                $res = '<strong>Félicitations</strong>, vous êtes actuellement <span id="incre">'.$i.'</span>'.$tt.' dans les résultats de recherche Google ! <br> Mais, êtes-vous sûr d’être dans le <strong>TOP 5</strong> pour tous vos mots clés ?';    
            break;
        }
      //  $title[$i] = '<h1>'.$h3->plaintext.'</h1>' ;
    }

    if($res !='')
        break;
}

//echo json_encode($arr);

if($res != ''){
    echo $res;  
    /*$json[] = array
    (
        'message' => $res
    );
    echo json_encode($json);*/
    flush();
}else{
    echo 'Arf ! Vous êtes positionné au-delà de la 1ère page Google, <strong>vous passez à côté de 90% des internautes ! </strong><br> Nous vous conseillons de mettre en place une stratégie de référencement naturel.';
    /*$json[] = array
    (
        'message' => 'Arf ! Vous êtes positionné au-delà de la 1ère page Google, <strong>vous passez à côté de 90% des internautes ! </strong><br> Nous vous conseillons de mettre en place une stratégie de référencement naturel.'
    );
    echo json_encode($json);*/
    flush();
}

?>
```

Sorry for my bad english !
Best regard,

Comment: Did you add anything to your .htaccess recently?

Comment: i try with a clean .htaccess and nothing change :/